# Key Event Handling using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, event-handling, tkinter, keyboard-shortcuts, keyevent

check the following link out :

[PyObjC Key Event Handling Question] [Key Events Handling using PyObjC in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630819/key-events-handling-using-pyobjc-in-mac-os-x)

This was my initial question. I somehow managed to find a built-in plugin to solve the Key Event Management, but using Python. It is called Tkinter.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def screenshot(*ignore): os.system("screencapture -s %s" % check_snapshot) 
root.bind('<Return>', greet)
root.mainloop(  )
```

On pressing return (enter) key, it would successfully call screenshot function, and it would work.

Now, what I am looking for is, whenever I press combination of keys, like Command+Shift+4, the above function should be call.

This should be done in the same manner for Command+Shift+3 and Command+Shift+5 as well.

This should be done by checking which combination of keys are pressed, and accordingly, their respective screenshot functions should be called.

Also, this app shortcuts shouldn't be just relied on this app's window or frame, the window / frame of this window shouldn't be visible, yet, the shortcuts should work and trigger their respective functions.

```
root.withdraw()
```

This is the built-in function which hides the Tkinter window, but then, I am unable to invoke any of the functions. These functions only work on Tkinter window, or else, keys shortcuts don't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter events only work when the tkinter window has focus,and for it to have focus it must be visible. You cannot use tkinter to handle events while another program is in the foreground.

The format of an event is `<modifier-modifier-event-detail>`, with *modifier* and *event* being optional. Event is something like `KeyPress`, `ButtonPress`, `ButtonRelease` and so on. Detail gives more detail, such as which key, or which button. For example, `<ButtonRelease-1>` is for releasing mouse button 1 (one).

Modifier is where you specify control, alt, delete or shift, and you can have more than one. Shift is a bit special, because it is often interpreted by the OS before tkinter ever sees is. So, for example, "Shift-3" on an American English keyboard is "#". Thus, instead of `<Shift-3>` you would use `<#>`.

Putting that all together, command-shift-3 would be `<Command-#>`. However, if you do that on a Mac, it will intercept that event and do a screenshot, so the binding will only work on Windows and Linux. On each OS there are a few key bindings you cannot override.

The best description of the format to use for specifying events is the [tcl/tk man page on bind](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm#M5). Even though you're asking about tkinter, the underlying engine is tcl/tk.

Comment: hey Bryan, thanks for helping. I will have a look at it and try implementing it...if I am stuck again, would let you know..thanks ... :)